# Wiring a lamp in

Tags: batteries, light, 12v

Hi guys I'm very new to electronic wiring so take it easy on me. I have a drone that I'm trying to connect a little 12v floodlight too so that it can see at night when it flys; the problem I'm having is that I have my battery outputting 12v and I try to connect it to the leads of the bulb and nothing?

My multimeter shows its outputting 11.53 volts (but I think that's a bad connection because the batteries are brand new) and I have an appropriate resistor but I haven't wired it in yet; wouldn't it work without the resistor though?

Confused why my bulb won't light up.
Specs on the bulb: 50w, 12v
Battery Specs: 6v each, 105mA each

ideas?!

Comment: You're bulb needs more voltage or you have burned it.

Comment: 50W at 12V makes 4.166A ( = 50W/12V).
Your battery can not deliver that much.

Comment: I'm assuming your drone has a camera on it, correct? If so, a much lower power option is IR LED's and an IR camera, much better for night viewing, and won't disturb others with more visible light.

Comment: what kind of battery are you using? can you share the datasheet?what kind of bulb are you trying to operate, 50 watt seems very big light for a drone.

Comment: It has sensors on the bottom of it, assuming they're IR sensors orrrr I'm not sure otherwise. The AR 2.0 by Parrot is the one I'm using.

Comment: AR 2.0 has an IR mod for it, search online for it. I haven't looked at the specifics but the existing camera probably just needs the IR filter removed and some IR LED's to illuminate the area below. The issue isn't just the current, it's the power draw in general, your existing 50W solution is a lot of power for mobile battery application.

Answer (score 2):

> Specs on the bulb: 50w, 12v

That's a current of 50/12 = 4.2 A

> Battery Specs: 6v each, 105mA each

How is a 105 mA battery going to supply 4.2 amps?

Or maybe you mean 105 mAh like this: -

[image]

Well 4.2 amps is going to deplete that battery in 1 minute and 30 seconds (if it can supply 4.2 A).

> I try to connect it to the leads of the bulb and nothing?

You were lucky and wired it incorrectly - don't do it again!

> I have an appropriate resistor but I haven't wired it in yet; wouldn't
>   it work without the resistor though?

Why would a 12V lamp need a resistor if powered from a *suitable* 12V power supply?

> My multimeter shows its outputting 11.53 volts (but I think that's a
>   bad connection because the batteries are brand new)

I wouldn't worry about that too much.

Comment: So what's a better option? A different bulb I assume? Which would be suitable for the power supply I have? Thank you!

Comment: What battery do you have (link to data)? What is the current lamp type (link)? That'll be a good start because it would be guesswork without this infor then more than likely find a decent LED module that is lightweight.